# Pandas rename csv columns & save

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv file consisting of three columns that I need to be renamed and saved to file.

Using this code, output is only displayed in terminal

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

print(df.columns)

df = df.rename(columns={'AREA':'SA2_code','Area':'SA2_name','Value':'RegSmokers_cnt'},
inplace=True)
```

Comment: What's read stays in memory. It's not automatically written to file. What's in memory statys in the memory until writing by using to_csv().

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code provided is that the inplace=True parameter is being used with the rename() method, which means the DataFrame is modified in place, and the method does not return a new DataFrame with the updated column names. That's why you don't see the updated columns when you print df.columns.

Try following:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

print(df.columns)

df_updated = df.rename(columns={'AREA': 'SA2_code', 'Area': 'SA2_name', 'Value': 'RegSmokers_cnt'})

print(df_updated.columns)

df_updated.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: The third column converts integers to real numbers, I only require integers. Do you have any ideas please

Comment: try to add this code under the third column: 

df_updated['RegSmokers_cnt'] = df_updated['RegSmokers_cnt'].astype(int)

Comment: I tried that and it still yields real numbers for that column